Ant Design Charts configuring color of the bars and the space between the group of bars
I'm having a hard time dealing with the Ant Design Charts, the Columns chart to be more specific. I can't find any definitive guide/documentation on it, the Ant Design web-site is mostly in Chinese and lacks the information. What I'm trying to do is - specify custom colors for the bars and control the gap between the groups of bars. Here's my component:


import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import React from 'react'
const Column = dynamic(() => import('@ant-design/plots').then(({ Column }) => Column), { ssr: false })

const ColumnChart = ({ data }) => {
    const config = {
        data,
        isGroup: true,
        xField: 'month',
        yField: 'value',
        seriesField: 'type',
        label: {
            textBaseline: 'bottom',
            text: (d) => `${d.value.toFixed(2)}%`,
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: 600,
                lineHeight: 20,
                '-webkit-text-stroke-width': 0.5,
                '-webkit-text-stroke-color': '#fff',
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88)',
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            showMarkers: false,
        },
        legend: false,
        height: 268,
        axis: {
            y: false,
            x: false,
        },
        style: {
            radiusTopLeft: 7,
            radiusTopRight: 7,
            radiusBottomRight: 7,
            radiusBottomLeft: 7,
            width: 20,
        },
        colorField: 'type',
        width: 450,
    } as any

    return (
        <div>
            <Column {...config} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ColumnChart



I've tried everything, specified the colors property, used both the style property and the marginRatio to control the gap between the groups of bars - nothing works, those settings just don't affect the chart at all. Does anybody know where to find any good documentation on this or how to do it?
Thanks!

for colors. just determine color field and give the palette you want as below.
{...
  colorField: "x",
  scale: {
    color: { range: COLOR_PALETTE },
  },
...
}

and my color palette is
const COLOR_PALETTE = [
 "#2389ff",
 "#0dcccc",
 "#f18e56",
 "#d787ff",
 "#7f6bff",
 "#68c738",
 "#c1952f",
 "#ff87cd",
 "#2f97b7",
 ]

the results is 
